# next_posts_link() in the same category

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if it's possible to limit `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` to a specific category in Wordpress.

I've got a website where I display one post every page. Clicking on next and previous arrow, it goes to next or previous post. However I would like to detect if the next or previous post is in the same category BEFORE loading it and remove prev/next arrow in case the post is not in the same category.

Here my partial code:

```
<?php if(in_category( '1' )) {
echo '<section class="next_nav">';
next_post_link('%link', '<img src="http://www.mywebsite.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/next_post.png">', TRUE);
echo '</section>';
echo '<section class="previous_nav">';
previous_post_link('%link', '<img src="http://www.mywebsite.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/previous_post.png">', TRUE);
echo '</section>';
}

else  {
echo '';
}

?>
```

When I click on next button, I get the next post but it's not in the same category. I was wondering if it was possible to use `get_next_post()` or `get_adjacent_post()` together with the previous function.

How can I get rid of it ?

Comment: What I can read out from the codex, what you are doing is right, because you set the 3rd parameter to `true`. Lets add an empty string for 4th parameter, and `'category'` for 5th. Maybe it will help. Anyway, in the codex: `If the post is in both the parent and subcategory, or more than one term, the next post link will lead to the next post in any of those terms.`

Comment: Is there any caching plugin? because your code is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies ! 
@lolka_bolka I tried, without results and no, there aren't caching plugins...

Comment: The problem is that next_post_link() works correctly but I can't find a way to detect if the next post is in the same category and - in this case - remove the next or previous arrow. In same cases it works as I expected, in others no...

Comment: Stefano did you find a solution??? mind sharing it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not tweaking the core code. 
Anyway I found a temporary solution: using ACF, I used a custom field for previous and another one for next post. I added manually the link I needed.